# Spring Boot 1.2.5.RELEASE - Sending E-mail via Gmail SMTP

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

> Firstly, I need to say that sending email with 1.2.0.RELEASE works fine

**application.properties:**

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username = *****@gmail.com
spring.mail.password = ****
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port = 465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback = false
```

**pox.xml**

```
<parent>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
     <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

.......

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

> After changing parent version to 1.2.5.RELEASE email sending hasn't worked

**Docs says:**
*If spring.mail.host and the relevant libraries (as defined by spring-boot-starter-mail) are available, a default JavaMailSender is created if none exists.*

**So i've added**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

It hasn't helped and then i've replaced it to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Also i've tried

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username = *****@gmail.com
spring.mail.password = ****
spring.mail.port = 465
```

**Result the same.**
It's not a problem to create and configure @Bean manually. But I want to use all beauty of Spring Boot.

Please point me to my mistakes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is the error message?

Comment: @dunni, There is not error message. Sender thread simply freezes

Comment: So you have a sample project using Spring Boot 1.2.0 and it works. And then you just change to spring boot 1.2.5 and then it breaks? Nothing has changed between those two versions as far as I can see. Can you share the project?

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll , [link](https://github.com/levgaas/SpringBoot-emailer) I've replaced my credentials with ***. Now it's 1.2.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It looks like there's a regression/behaviour change in Java Mail. [The change](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/revision/704) is in both 1.5.3 and 1.5.4. Your app works with Boot 1.2.0 as it uses Java Mail 1.5.2. It fails with Boot 1.2.5 as it uses Java Mail 1.5.4.

The problem in 1.5.3+ appears to be that the SMTP transport connects on port 465 and GMail expects an SSL handshake. Java Mail incorrectly thinks it's not using SSL so it never initiates the handshake and the connection attempt (eventually) times out. You can convince Java Mail to do the right thing by being explicit about the use of SSL. Add the following to `application.properties`:

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true
```

Comment: Worked for me as well. I had an additional error due to my antivirus. Once I disabled mail protection on it, the message was sent successfully

Comment: This answer was very useful. I used it, along with the use of spring-boot's "spring.mail.test-connection=true", to quickly solve my issue.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it is a regression. I have created [#3624](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3624) to investigate the issue. Thanks for the sample project!