# No exception found but mail not send in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-mvc

I am new in `spring MVC` i have got an issue while send email through spring . no exception will occur but  mail not send.

my applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">  
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />  

        <property name="username" value="uname" />  
        <property name="password" value="pass" />  
        <property name="javaMailProperties">  
            <props>  
               <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>  
              <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port">465</prop>  
              <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>  
              <prop key="mail.smtp.port">465</prop>  
            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>
```

my controller class

```
@Controller
public class WebController {

//    System.out.println("suceees");
    @Autowired
     private JavaMailSender mailSender;  

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {

        return "index";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirect() {

         sendMail();
        return "redirect:finalPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/finalPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String finalPage() {


        return "final";
    }

    public void sendMail() {

        try {
            MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
            helper.setFrom("sender");
            helper.setTo("receiver");
            helper.setSubject("hi");
            helper.setText("welcome");

            // attach the file
            FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(new File("/home/ajmal/Pictures/messi.jpg"));
            helper.addAttachment("messi.jpg", file);//image will be sent by this name

            mailSender.send(message);
 } catch (MailException | MessagingException ex) {

            System.err.println("error");

        }

    }
}
```

thanks in advance .. no exception will occur. but mail not send ?

Comment: Did you tried Simple Java program to send the mail? http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Comment: in your actual code do you replace `sender` & `receiver` with actual mail id  or not?

Comment: i run with actual mail id

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had into the same problem sometime back, with Spring Boot 1.2.5. Looks like with the latest version of Java Mail, now another property is needed - `spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable` to be set as `true`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721298/spring-boot-1-2-5-release-sending-e-mail-via-gmail-smtp#31726855) for details.

Also, when I tested my application, I saw that  merely giving the regular gmail password didn't anymore work. I needed a [2-step verified](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/) account, and had to use an [application password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en).